# Not recieving values sent via AJAX POST to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying I'm trying to send a specific section of my URL string, to my php file, to then populate my page accordingly. Everything is working fine, except for the AJAX POST method. I've tried doing var_dump of the POST variable in my PHP, and my array is empty (so I know nothing is getting through).

The success DOES return as being passed, so I don't know where the data is going. I'm testing locally on XAMPP, and I've combed through SoF and no luck on any of the fixes. My code is below.

Screen shot of page:

[image]

jQuery AJAX Request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    str = window.location.href;
    pos = str.search("pages/"); //42
    send = str.slice(42, -5);
    console.log(send);
    console.log(pos);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "retrieve.php",
        data: {
            tom: send
        },
        success: function() {
            $.get("retrieve.php", function(data, status) {
                    $("#main").html(data);
                }) //ends GET function   
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log(arguments)
        }
    }); //ends POST request               
}); //ends DOC-READY function
```

PHP:

```
echo "<i>hello</i>";
echo var_dump($_POST);
$url = $_POST['tom'];
json_decode($url);
echo $url;
```

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the code so you can get the basic steps down. Maybe try just posting something basic to the page and see if you get the expected results.

Comment: Hey, yes, I'm getting the web page up, I just need to retrieve my data out of the DB to fill certain fields on the page based off the URL. And to make sure my GET request is working, I had it return the data from the php file onto the page, and that works fine. Its just the POST not working

Comment: Perhaps try watching the console for the `POST` request and make sure the data is being sent. If the value for `tom` is `null` that might cause the issue.

Comment: @camelCase : what exactly would I log to the console ? I logged my value for "tom" earlier in the code with console.log(send); and it was valid

Comment: Are you looking at the browser console? Are there errors and if not has the post definitely happened?  Also if using wordpress or similar, often the "results.php" are not in the directory of the where the browser things the code is running, even if the javascript is in the same location.

Comment: @brianlmerritt i just posted a screenshot. Not using WP,just my own code

Comment: And everything is in the same directory

Comment: I would first try getting rid of the GET request and just try writing data to #main directly in the success function.

Comment: I don't mean logging to console, I mean to inspect the `POST` during/after the `AJAX` request is fired. Looks like you're using FF so you should be able to see the parameters that were sent in the `POST`

Comment: What is the PHP page doing with the POST data? If all you are doing is retrieving data, why do a POST and then a GET to the same page? Sounds like it should be one or the other with the results displayed to the page.

Comment: @ckimbrell : basically what I'm doing is, taking my substring for a given month, taking that value and POST to the server. Then querying my DB for all results matching that month. After than I'm using GET to return the value. But after typing this comment out, I just realized that, that would be foolish. Thank you for the catch lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below,

Also you don't need to `json_decode` unless you send a json request,And please make sure **all the post values** are passing.

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var str = window.location.href;
    var pos = str.search("pages/"); //42
    var send = str.slice(42, -5);
    console.log(send);
    console.log(pos);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "retrieve.php",
        data: {
            'tom': send//make sure this is not empty
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(arguments) {
            console.log(arguments)
        }
    }); //ends POST request               
}); //ends DOC-READY function
```

PHP:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    //echo "<i>hello</i>";
    //echo var_dump($_POST);
    $url = $_POST['tom'];
    json_encode($url);
    echo $url;
}
```

Comment: I will try this when I get back to my desk in a few. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Quick question: when you say "check to see if the post values are passing" are you asking for me to ensure that the "send" variable has valid data in it, or on the server side if I'm getting the values

Comment: @JustinE.Samuels i'm asking whether the send variable is having correct data.

Comment: Yes it does, I checked it.

Comment: Hey still no dice. Same result. It's really weird because I've looked over and over on the JQuery docs, and everything seems correct

Comment: @JustinE.Samuels what can you see in the console?

Comment: This going to sound crazy, but i literally gave up and turned my Apache server off and back on, and it worked -_-, either way, terrific answer and thank you sir